# ThreadLocal variable is null between Thread and Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-local

I use a **Thread** for each incoming request to the application. At first, I set a flag in the Thread's constructor by **MDC** class in **SLF4J** and fetched it in the Runnable's run method but the value was null. I guessed the problem was related to **MDC** class so I was going to use originally **ThreadLocal** possibility instead of **SLF4J** however I was wrong and the code has not worked correctly yet.
My code is :

```
public class CustomThread extends Thread
{
     public static      ThreadLocal<String> status = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public  CustomThread(CustomRunnable target)
    {
         super(target);
         status.set("Start");
    }
}

public class CustomRunnable implements Runnable
{
      public void run()
      {
               System.out.println(CustomThread.status.get());
       }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
      CustomThread t1 = new CustomThread(new CustomRunnable());
      t1.start();
}
```

and the result was :

```
The flag is : null
```

Is there anything else that I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see value of ThreadLocal only in thread which set it. In your code you set ThreadLocal in thread main and read it in another tread - CustomThread.